# If $T(n+1)=T(n)+\lfloor \sqrt{n+1}, \rfloor$ $\forall n\geq 1$, what is $T(m^2)$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

> $T(n+1)=T(n)+\lfloor \sqrt{n+1} \rfloor$ $\forall n\geq 1$ 
>   $T(1)=1$
>   The value of $T(m^2)$ for m ≥ 1 is?

Clearly you cannot apply master theorem because it is not of the form $T(n)=aT(\frac{n}{b})+f(n)$
So I tried Back Substitution:
$T(n)=T(n-1)+\sqrt{n}$
$T(n-1)=T(n-2)+\sqrt{n-1}$
therefore,
$T(n)=T(n-2)+\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n}$
$T(n)=T(n-3)+\sqrt{n-2}+\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n}$
.
.
$T(n)=T(n-(n-1))+...T(n-k)+\sqrt{n-(k-1)}+...+\sqrt{n-2}+\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n}$
.
.
$T(n)=T(1)+...T(n-k)+\sqrt{n-(k-1)}+...+\sqrt{n-2}+\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n}$
$T(n)=T(1)+...+\sqrt{n-2}+\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n}$
I'm stuck up here, how to solve this ahead?

Comment: Are you looking for an asymptotic or a closed form?

Comment: @Meelo : a closed form. This is the link to the question -http://geeksquiz.com/gate-gate-cs-2003-question-35/

Comment: Master theorem won't give you a closed form, but an asymptotic. As a side note, check out what happens when you replace n with n - 1, and also: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+floor%28sqrt%28j%29%29%2C+j%3D1+to+n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Noting that $T(1)=1=\lfloor \sqrt{1}\rfloor$, so far, you've narrowed it down to the form (although you forgot the floor symbols, which are important):

$$T(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$$

which is correct; to solve this, notice that if we calculated $T(4^2-1)=T(15)$ thusly, for instance, the sum would expand as (after we lay it out very suggestively):
$$\begin{align*}T(n)&=1+1+1\\&+2+2+2+2+2\\&+3+3+3+3+3+3+3\end{align*}$$
Notice the pattern here: The is $3$ integers such that $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor =1$ - that is $i$ with $1^2\leq i < 2^2$. There are $5$ such that $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor =3$ - that is, those with $2^2 \leq i < 3^2$. More generally, there are $2n+1$ integers $i$ such that $\lfloor \sqrt{i}\rfloor =n$, being those in the range $[n^2,(n+1)^2)$ which has length $$(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1.$$

To use this, consider $T(n^2-1)$. The sum will look like:
$$\begin{align*}T(n)&=1+1+1\\&+2+2+2+2+2\\&+3+3+3+3+3+3+3\\&\qquad\qquad \vdots\\&+\underbrace{(n-1)+(n-1)+\ldots+(n-1)}_{\text{$2n-1$ times}}\end{align*}$$
which can be grouped as:
$$\begin{align*}T(n)&=3\cdot 1\\&+5\cdot 2\\&+7\cdot 3\\&\quad\,\,\vdots\\
&+(2i+1)\cdot i\\&\quad\,\,\vdots \\&+(2n-1)\cdot (n-1)\end{align*}$$
or, as a sum:
$$T(n^2-1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(2i+1)\cdot i = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}2i^2 + i$$
and knowing the identities that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i = \frac{1}2(n^2-n)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2=\frac{1}6(2n^3-3n^2+n)$ which can easily be verified (or found) using induction, the above can be written as
$$T(n^2-1)=\frac{2}3n^3 -\frac{1}2n^2-\frac{1}6n.$$
From here, any other value is easy to determine - for instance, if $x$ is such that $x<(n+1)^2$ and $x=(n^2-1)+c$, then $T(x)=T(n^2-1)+cn$.

Comment: Does $T(4^2-1)=T(15)$ mean that you substituted $n=m^2$ in the equation and then solved for $T(m^2-1)$?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything deeper than $4^2-1=15$. I just used that to clarify the property of $15$ that I was working with; but, most my post deals with the value of $T(m^2-1)$.

Comment: I maybe missing something but the answer to T(m^2) is $\frac{m}{6} (4m^2 - 3m + 5)$

Comment: Yes; this can be found, since my expression gives $T(m^2)=T(m^2-1)+m$, which factors to that.

Comment: I'm having trouble deriving the equation at the end after you said "using induction, the above can be written as". Can you explain how you derived it by induction and how can we get
$T(m)=\frac{m}{6}(4m^2-3m+5)$? I'm very close to understand it totally except for the end.

Comment: Well, those two identities are well known ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number)). You can prove that a polynomial $P$ of degree $d$ has that $Q(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}P(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $d+1$, so you can just compute (from the sum) $Q(1),Q(2),\ldots,Q(d+2)$ and compute the Lagrange polynomial and be guaranteed that it is correct. The proof of this would be too long for a comment, and not wholly relevant to this question, but it would make a fine question on its own, and I could answer it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19640/discussion-between-sidsec9-and-meelo).

Comment: About the 2nd identity, sum of squares of $n$ natural numbers, why is $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2=\frac{1}6(2n^3-3n^2+n)$ instead of $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2=\frac{1}6(2n^3+3n^2+n)$?

Comment: Well, the particular thing on the page I link to is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2=\frac{1}6(2n^3+3n^2+n)$ - but notice the the upper limit of the sum is $n$, whereas I have $n-1$. If you replace $n$ by $(n-1)$ and expand the polynomials, you'll get what I wrote.